# Request timeout with 200 and refresh header

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have a simple php script running on Ubuntu 14, Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9.  Every once and a while the request seems to stall, and after about 40 secs (normally < 100ms), it responds with an empty page, 200 OK and a Refresh header to the same URL.  I think it's happening more often, if there hasn't been a recent request to the script for a while.

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh: 1; URL=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/script.php?t=1407272586793
Connection: Close
```

Script content:

```
<?php
//# Provide server time
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo '{"time":"'. gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s") .' +0000"}';
```

There doesn't seem to be a record of the request in either the Apache access or error logs.

I'm not sure how to find at what point this is stalling.  Has anyone experienced this before, or have any suggestion on how I might debug this further?

Comment: Those headers are probably being sent before the actual content is generated, then when the script hangs, no content is echoed.  Where to start? I would say with items that have points of failure, SQL queries, for loops, while loops.  Start narrowing down the conditions to create the problem, your gut says it's when you don't receive a request for a long period, If you're getting a lot of traffic, it could also be that you're not properly closing mysql handles and you're waiting for a connection to free up from mysql.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  When I say my script is simple.. i mean reaally simple.  It sets a CORS header and echoes the current time.

Comment: The fact that there are no error logs indicates to me that your browser or client is not receiving the full package.  Like a simple latency issue between client and server.

Comment: When I netstat the server, I can see that the connection is in a `SYN_RECV` state.  Any idea what might cause that?